# Firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase cloud function to **create new document from another document**.

Basically, i have a **field in a document** called **reps {} that takes userId as Key and and int as value**.

i want to check if the **sum** of the **values in reps {}** is greater than 100(example).

i have an onUpdate function that works perfectly but i need to add this feature. i tried this:

```
var count = 0;
admin.firestore()
  .collection("posts")
  .doc(userId)
  .collection("userPosts")
  .doc(postId).get().then(doc =>
  { 
    doc['reps'].values.forEach(val =>
    { 
      count += val;
     });
  });

  console.log(count);
```

With this query i get the reps map, **How can i calculate the sum of all value** **inside a map**:

```
admin
  .firestore()
  .collection("posts")
  .doc(userId)
  .collection("userPosts")
  .doc(postId).get().then(function (doc)
  {
    if (doc.exists)
    {
      console.log(doc.get("reps"));
    }
  });
```

Comment: I think you don't get documents directly from the above written query. See this: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#get

Comment: @UmarHussain, Thanks for your reply. So how shoul i write my query??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing

```
admin.firestore()
  .collection("posts")
  .doc(userId)
  .collection("userPosts")
  .doc(postId).get()
```

you are querying one document and the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get) method returns a Promise that resolves with a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) .

Therefore, doing

```
doc['reps'].values
```

will not work.

You need to use the DocumentSnapshot's [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#get) method, as follows:

```
admin.firestore()
  .collection("posts")
  .doc(userId)
  .collection("userPosts")
  .doc(postId).get().then(doc =>
  { 
    var respObj = doc.get('reps');
    Object.entries(respObj).forEach(([key, value]) => { 
      count += value;
     });
  });
```

Comment: Yeah, i just figured it out. Thanks for you reply.

Comment: I tried your code and in firebase console i get this error : **TypeError: doc.get(...).forEach is not a function**

Comment: Yes, see the update, there was a mistake in my code!

Answer (score 0):

So i just figured it out:

> i used **get()** to get the field i was looking for.
>
> To calculate the **sum of values** i used:
>
> `Object.keys(rep).forEach(function (values)
>         {
>           var value = rep[values];
>           repCount += value;
>         });`

Here's my code:

```
await admin
  .firestore()
  .collection("posts")
  .doc(userId)
  .collection("userPosts")
  .doc(postId).get().then(function (doc)
  {
    if (doc.exists)
    {
      var rep = doc.get("reps");
      Object.keys(rep).forEach(function (values)
      {
        var value = rep[values];
        repCount += value;
      });
    }
  });
```